# Continous Unuathorised message response on using authguard in nest .js

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to use the authguard here in nest js but i am getting this unauthorized error constantly , let me share all the codes here

```
//auth service
import { Injectable, UseFilters } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateAuthDto } from './dto/create-auth.dto';
import { UpdateAuthDto } from './dto/update-auth.dto';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthDocument ,Auth } from './Schema/userAuth';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Auth.name) private AuthModel:Model<AuthDocument> ,private JwtService :JwtService){

  };


  create(createAuthDto: CreateAuthDto):Promise<Auth> {
    console.log(createAuthDto);
   const user=  new this.AuthModel;
   user.Name= createAuthDto.Name;
   user.Username= createAuthDto.Username;
   user.Email = createAuthDto.Email;
   user.Password = createAuthDto.Password;
    return user.save();
  }
  
  async login(Username: string, Password: string): Promise<any> {

    try {
      const user = await this.AuthModel.findOne({ Username:Username }).exec();
      if(!user){
        return 'user not found' ;
      }
      if(user.Password == Password){
      
      
        const payload = { Username ,Password} ;
    const accessToken = this.JwtService.sign(payload)
     console.log(payload);
     console.log(accessToken);
       
        return {accessToken};
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error finding user:', error);
      return 'Error finding user';
    }
  }
  findAll() {
    return `This action returns all auth`;
  }

  findOne(Email:string) :Promise<Auth> {
    const user = this.AuthModel.findOne({Email:Email})
    return user;
  }

  update(id: number, updateAuthDto: UpdateAuthDto) {
    return `This action updates a #${id} auth`;
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    return `This action removes a #${id} auth`;
  }
}
```

```
//auth module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { userSchema ,Auth} from './Schema/userAuth';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';
import { LocalGuard } from './guards/local.guard';

@Module({
  imports:[MongooseModule.forFeature([{name:Auth.name,schema:userSchema}]) ,
  JwtModule.register({
    secret:"H@rsh123",
    signOptions:{
      expiresIn:"1h"
    }
  }),PassportModule],
  controllers: [AuthController ],
  providers: [AuthService ,LocalStrategy ,LocalGuard],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
//auth control
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Patch, Param, Delete, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { CreateAuthDto } from './dto/create-auth.dto';
import { UpdateAuthDto } from './dto/update-auth.dto';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalGuard } from './guards/local.guard';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('signup')
  create(@Body() createAuthDto: CreateAuthDto) {
    return this.authService.create(createAuthDto);
  }
  @Post('login')
  @UseGuards(LocalGuard)
  async login(@Body() requestBody:{Username:string ,Password :string}){
    const {Username , Password} = requestBody;
    const user= await this.authService.login(Username , Password);
    
    if(!user){
      return 'invalid user';
    }
    return user;
  }
  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.authService.findAll();
  }

  @Get(':Username')
  findOne(@Param('Username') Username: string) {
    return this.authService.findOne(Username);
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateAuthDto: UpdateAuthDto) {
    return this.authService.update(+id, updateAuthDto);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  remove(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.authService.remove(+id);
  }
}
```

```
//local-strategy
// local.strategy.ts
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(payLoad :any): Promise<any> {
    const {username,password} = payLoad;
    console.log('user', username, password);
    const user = await this.authService.login(username, password);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

```
//localguard
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()

export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local'){
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('hello');
        return super.canActivate(context);
    }
}
```

everything works correctly if I remove thw @UseGuards() but when i use it it always gives unauthorized error with 401 code , the validate function isnt even being called because the console.log statement doesnt print on the output, please help

Comment: Are you sending `Username` and `Password` or `username` and `password` in the request body?

Comment: I'm sending Username and Password

Answer (score 0):

Passport expects you to send `username` and `password` as fields of the request body. If you want to use something else, like `Username`, and yes, capitalization matters, then you need to tell passport about this change. You can do so by passing options to the `super` method of the `LocalStrategy` constructor, e.g.

```js
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'Username',
      passwordField: 'Password',
    });
  }

  async validate(username :string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('user', username, password);
    const user = await this.authService.login(username, password);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Also take note that the `validate` method has two parameters, the `username` field value and the `password` field value.

Comment: Ohh, I almost scratched my head trying to tweak things to solve the error here.. thankyou for the help ,man! Really thankyou. I'm trying to upvote but can't because I'm a newbie and don't have enough reputation but you have my gratitude!